# Issues with texture painting an arm

Tags: texture-painting, normals

I got the answer I needed for the normals, now the issue is that I can't paint the same arm. The normals are all facing outside, the only difference is that the arm is orange instead of red like the rest of the body. I'm not selecting anything and it's casually an orange red. It's not letting me paint on the limb at all, I'm unsure of what is happening and I don't know of a possible source besides the normal.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to invert the normals, select all and press Shift N, if it still doesn't work please share your file

Comment: It doesn't work, unfortunately for some reason blender won't let me share the file and let others access it. I am just having a very either buggy or corrupted time over here

Comment: Use https://blend-exchange.com/ or another platform like workupload